# Как управлять скоростью скачивания файла?

Tags: apache, файлы, php, сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как управлять скоростью отдачи файла с сервера? Есть ли какие-то встроенные функции или библиотеки на PHP? Дайте источники, где можно подробнее ознакомится с этим вопросом.

Comment: если просто на php можно файл читать и отдавать блоки медленно

Comment: очень, очень плохой совет.

Comment: @klopp это очень очень плохая идея :) что я могу сделать, еще есть tc и прочие iproute но в рамках php ничего лучше нет. к тому-же это не совет, просто то что знаю говорю, иначе сделал бы ответом.

Comment: Так и не надо делать это на php вообще :) Потому что отдачу "чтением и записью в stdout" лучше делать только для маленьких файлов, но для них ограничения смысла не имеют.

Comment: а как же тогда реализуется (не в рамкаx php) в общем ограничение???

Comment: Сервером. А серверы и способы бывают разные.

Answer (score 2):

В nginx этоделается на уровне конфигурации location:

```
location ^~ /videos/ {
    ...
    #до 1 мб можно скачивать без лимита
    limit_rate_after 1m;
    #ограничить скорость до 150 кбит
    limit_rate 150k;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для apache можно использовать [mod_bandwidth](http://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/www/mod_bandwidth/), но так никто не делает.